# Plotting scatterplots with subset of rasters in R according to land cover

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, scatterplot

I have three rasters:

```
> raster1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 31.72  (min, max)

> landcoverraster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/XX.tif 
names      : landusemaskedme 
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
attributes :
       ID
 from:  1
  to : 12
```

I would like to plot scatterplots between raster1 and raster2 according to landcover types in landcoverraster. But first I would like to subset a random subset of raster1 and raster2 (as they are very large rasters and when I plot scatterplots it gives a big chuncky scatterplot) according to landcover type. How can I subset a random raster according to land cover type and plot a scatterplot between raster1 and raster2? I am looking a desired output similar to this
[image: desired output]

What I initally have done (without subsetting), and came up with this plot:

```
plot(raster1[landcoverrraster==1],raster2[landcoverraster==1])
```

[image: myresult]

Reproducible rasters:

library(raster)

```
ras1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))
ras2 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))

#Generating landcover example data
raster2 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),ncol =3))
raster2 <- as.factor(raster2)

rat <- levels(raster2 )[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers")
levels(raster2 ) <- rat
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example rasters didn't have the same resolution, so I added rows to ras1 and ras2 to remedy that. Furthermore, in the code below I used `sampleRandom()` which returns a simple random sample. Depending on your data, sample size and reason for drawing a sample you could also consider employing `sampleRegular()`, or `sampleStratified()` using the different landcover types as the strata. You write that you want to draw a sample to avoid 'chunky' scatter-plots, but you could consider binning/aggregating the data for visualisation instead. Anyway, here is one approach:

```
library(raster)

# Example from question with expanded ras1 and ras2 to match resolution
ras1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)))
ras2 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)))
ras3 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)))
ras3 <- as.factor(ras3)
rat <- levels(ras3)[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers")
levels(ras3) <- rat

# Create raster stack
rs <- stack(ras1, ras2, ras3)

# Find a simple random sample of the stack, equating to 90% of the cells.
rs_sr <- sampleRandom(rs, ncell(rs)*0.9, cells = TRUE)
# Use the returned cell numbers to extract the sample from the raster stack. 
# Return this as a data frame and with factor values for the landcover layer.
sr_df <- extract(rs, rs_sr[,1], factors = TRUE, df = TRUE)

# Rename columns 
names(sr_df) <- c('ID', 'ras1', 'ras2', 'landcover')
# Retrieve subset of values by the "land" landcover
land <- sr_df[which(sr_df$landcover == "land"),]

# Plot. Since the values for the "land" landcover are all 1 on the 
# two example rasters, this doesn't look like much of course.
plot(land$ras1, land$ras2)
```

[image]